How to handle different enp*s0 interfaces with networking.service?
I use the networking through the networking.service and the /etc/network/interfaces configuration file on a Debian 12 system (as shown here).
Problem
I added a GPU and after rebooting, the computer was offline. It's a NAS without display, so I had to connect a screen and a keyboard.
And I saw that ip addr reported a new interface: enp3s0.
Problem: my configuration in /etc/network/interfaces only mentioned enp2s0:
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug enp2s0

iface enp2s0 inet dhcp

Temporary solution
I had to replace enp2s0 with enp3s0 and run systemctl restart networking to get the network back, and it worked.
If someday I remove the GPU or add a PCI-Express device, the name of the network interface may change again and the server would go offline.
So I changed the conf file in order to manage enp2s0 or enp3s0:
# The primary network interface
# without GPU
allow-hotplug enp2s0

iface enp2s0 inet dhcp

# with GPU
allow-hotplug enp3s0

iface enp3s0 inet dhcp

Definitive solution?
Is it safe to declare conf for interfaces that may or may not exist? Is there a cleaner way?

One option for a cleaner solution is to disable predictable interface names. If you only have a single interface on your system, it will always be eth0.
Another option would be to rename the interface by first identifying it by its MAC address. This is described in the same document; for example, given an interface with MAC address 52:54:00:bb:a4:80, I could place the following in /etc/systemd/network/10-lan0.link:
[Match]
MACAddress=52:54:00:bb:a4:80
[Link]
Name=lan0

Now whenever the system boots, the interface with that MAC address will be named lan0.
I would then write /etc/network/interfaces like this:
allow-hotplug lan0
iface lan0 inet dhcp

Because the interface is identified by its MAC address, this will work regardless of what other cards you have installed in your system.

I think the initial poster's solution, duplicate extra interface names, is already the best. Starting from the requirements (headless server, NAS, limited hardware changes), here's why:

Focus on the needs:

Needs: Enable DHCP on any interface and don't get locked out, which also includes surviving software updates over the years.

The smallest, simplest way to ensure that DHCP is enabled for any NIC, without systemd or udev complexity, is CATCHALL INTERFACE NAMING

This lets us avoid systemd rules for renaming interfaces, and udev rules, both of which are dynamic, programable and sophisticated, yet won't add any benefit for this use-case, and create extra failure points:

systemd to rename based on mac address or even wildcard matching works well, but if your initrd doesn't regenerate, that rule may be ignored. You also need to alter /etc/network/interfaces to match the rule.

udev can also do the same, identifying a NIC by MAC address or wildcard, but then requires a script to configure the interface eg interface=$1;ip link set dev $interface up;dhclient $interface





Mentioned in Debian docs as CATCHALL INTERFACE NAMING under Networking, specifically config #Safety_nets. It's mentioned as an acceptable way to add robustness to a system, where edge-cases can still surprise you


An example
Starting with your example, create extra interface records for a reasonable number of possible names:
# /etc/networking/interfaces
allow-hotplug enp2s0
iface enp2s0 inet dhcp
# next duplicate set
allow-hotplug enp3s0
iface enp3s0 inet dhcp
# next duplicate set
allow-hotplug enp4s0
iface enp4s0 inet dhcp
# etc ...


Alternatives to consider, with opinions for each:
Work, but too deeply tied with system upgrades and other complexity

systemd link rules (mentioned above)
udev rules (mentioned above)

Hacky and should work, but untested benefit over "top" solution (catch all of interface names)

wildcards in /etc/networking/interfaces eg allow-hotplug enp* / iface enp* inet dhcp

Works well, but likely not worthwhile

netplan, from netplan.io package, can control interfaces, match names, and delegate to other systems, like NetworkManager, but defaults to systemd

This sample config matches names, and then tells systemd (via networkd renderer) to enable dhcp. Run sudo netplan apply
# /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    matched:
      match:
        name: enp*s0  # Matches interfaces like enp0s0, enp1s0, etc.
      dhcp4: yes


network-manager package, controlled via nmcli or nmtui if you want a TUI. Usually a GUI tool for desktops, it uses yaml files internally that are easy to use.

sample config, note path, and remember to run sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
# /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/my-auto-ethernet-wpl.nmconnection
[connection]
id=my-auto-ethernet-wpl
type=ethernet
interface-name=wpl*  # Wildcard to match interfaces starting with "wpl"
autoconnect=true

[ipv4]
method=auto


Any config management systems like salt, ansible, puppet, etckeeper can configure your system and handle errors.

If you know how to use any of these, the complexity is lowered, and it should be maintainable, especially when combined with version control.



